# "Too many open files error" hit when I run my application on Java8

Tags: lucene, java-8

I have a search engine based on a custom implementation of Lucene and unfortunately I am still on Lucene 3.0.3 and I can't change it for reasons that are out of scope of this question.
Now I have a requirement to move from Java 6 to Java 8, however when I run the indexing using Java 8 JVM, I hit "Too many open files issue" as below:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /myIndex/_27c.fdx (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:333)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:257)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexOutput.<init>(SimpleFSDirectory.java:180)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory.createOutput(NIOFSDirectory.java:85)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldsWriter.<init>(FieldsWriter.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter.initFieldsWriter(StoredFieldsWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter.finishDocument(StoredFieldsWriter.java:144)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsWriter$PerDoc.finish(StoredFieldsWriter.java:192)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$WaitQueue.writeDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:1559)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter$WaitQueue.add(DocumentsWriter.java:1578)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.finishDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:1155)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:832)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:807)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:2155)
```

The ulimit on my system is 80.000 files and when I run lsof, I get that the open files belong to the index and they are marked as (deleted) segments.
I am aware that there are tons of questions, answers and blogs about the Lucene open files issue, however:

- I've already tried whatever is recommended (review the code looking for open IndexWriters, increase ulimit, enable
  compound files, decrease number of segments from 10 to 4, review the code for open files) without success and
- The issue didn't appear with java6 so I am guessing that the problem is in how java8 handles files.

Anybody faced this issue with java 8 before? Any additional idea about how to further troubleshoot this issue or what could be the cause?

Comment: I would check for anywhere that you are opening an `IndexReader`, but not closing it. Remember, closing an `IndexSearcher` does *not* close the underlying reader.

Comment: @femtoRgon - i already checked, however please notice that the application is working well on Java6. If I left some files open I would expect to see the issue in Java 6 as well and not only in Java8.

Comment: you haven't closed the file which you might have opened by InputStream to that file

Comment: @AR1 - Yes, I did see that, but in all honestly, wasn't *quite* sure whether I bought it. There may have been something in Java 8 that *exacerbated* an existing problem. If you have 70000 file handles left open in Java 6, and 80000 in Java 8, you have a resource leak either way, and should find the cause of it.